# I want to filter the method List in yourkit

Tags: yourkit

Is it possible to make the method list displayed in yourkit not show anything but the ones I am interested in?　You can set it up in [settings] - [filters], but it comes out as an outlined arrow. I don't want this to appear.

[image]